# Clojure - return value from db query

Tags: clojure

I want to `created post` as return value just after execute my db query function. Here is one example from my db functions:

```
(defn add-post-record [post]
   (sql/with-connection
    db
    (sql/insert-record :post post )))
```

and what i need in my route is something like:

```
(def post (db/add-post-record {:title title
                             :body body
                             :owner user
                             :isdraft isdraft}))
```

Then i am gonna use this like: `(:id post)`

I am so new in clojure. This may be a very simple problem but i am stuck.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not test this right now, but reading the documentation of insert-record and with-connection, I think something like:

```
(defn add-post-record [post]
 (let [keys (sql/with-connection db
              (sql/insert-record :post post ))]
   (merge post keys))
```

It is not very clear to me what exactly the map returned by insert-record contains, try it out.

Comment: i am gonna check this out a few hours later. gonna tell you the result. thanks